# How to compare Likert ratings for multiple methods in a usability study

Tags: statistical-significance, likert

I am designing a questionnaire to compare user experience of usage of a two prototypes of a software - prototype A and B. Users will rate prototype A for a task and then prototype B for performing the same task based on a 5 point Likert scale. The questionnaire will contain 5 questions related to the various measures of user experience and contain ratings for each measure. How can i compare the Likert ratings for the two prototypes using statistical tests?

Comment: Median for central tendency, inter-quartile range for dispersion, [Wilcoxon's signed-rank test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) for testing median difference.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight; i was reading the wikipedia article on the Wilcoxon signed-rank test..is there an example with a software package that i can follow such as Matlab/Excel/SPSS, particular to my case? i am getting confused by the volume of stats jargon(being a software dev and not a ux specialist)..thanks

Comment: Here is a site on [how to do it in four common software](https://wikis.uit.tufts.edu/confluence/display/SSSI/Wilcoxon+Signed-Rank+Test)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to summarize the comments into an answer.

For comparing ordinal variables like Likert's scale, you may consider using median to represent the central tendency, and inter-quartile range to show the dispersion.

If you would like to formally test the difference in mean rank, you can use [Wikcoxon's signed-rank test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test). Here is a [wiki](https://wikis.uit.tufts.edu/confluence/display/SSSI/Wilcoxon+Signed-Rank+Test) describing how to do it is SPSS, Stata, SAS, and R.

If you would like to test if the medians are equal, [sign test](http://academic.udayton.edu/gregelvers/psy216/spss/ordinaldata.htm) is another option, as suggested by ttnphns in the comment.

Comment: **Wilcoxon sign-rank test** is a 2-related-samples test which tests H0 that the difference between the two variables is symmetric about 0. **Sign test** tests H0 that this difference has median 0.

Comment: @ttnphns Thanks for the correction. I have edited the answer to reflect the difference.

Comment: Please don't be hurry. `difference in mean rank`, `the medians are equal`. How do you see it with a _paired-sample_ test?

Comment: @ttnphns In that case I am probably confused by your phrase "between the two variable is symmetric about 0." Since this is a wiki, please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight do i have to do  a-priori power analysis for determining the sample size for administering 5 Likert scale questionnaire..or can i randomly choose the number as 10 participants?

Comment: @iceman I do believe so. I am not very familiar with effect sizes of non-parametric tests, it is certainly possible. Here is a [SE thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30455/how-to-determine-the-effect-size-of-a-wilcoxon-rank-sum-test-in-r) and an [article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1541-0420.2008.01062.x/abstract;jsessionid=2F19AE99435F55C2C460D0CFC3C39182.d01t02) for your reference.

Comment: I found a link mentioning the statistics to calculate:http://www.icbl.hw.ac.uk/ltdi/cookbook/info_likert_scale/index.html . is there a simple worked out example for Likert items treated as ordinal data?

Comment: @iceman, try Google [wilcoxon's Signed-rank test example](https://www.google.com/search?q=wilcoxon+signed+rank+test+example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) and [sign test example](https://www.google.com/search?q=sign+test+example&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a). Good luck!